# gwt component to auto-complete text

Tags: gwt2

I am using Google Web Toolkit to create a web based XML and Code editor- in this code/xml data will be in a text area... What I want to do is allow code auto-completion- so when user starts typing some text, the possible complete values for the partially typed in text are shown, now user can either select one of the shown values, or type in the entire value.

Is there a GWT component that does this? The only thing that I could think of is using a Tooltip to show possible auto-completion options, and enable the user to select one of the values from the tooltip (this value should then be entered into the text area).

Is this the only approach to solve my problem? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

GWT library has very robust SuggestBox component for that. See description and example here:
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html

Plus, I'd recommend to review a video tutorial how to use it:
http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/building-an-autocomplete-service-in-gwt-screencast-part-3-getting-the-server-code-to-send-a-basic-response/

Actually there are set of videos, but suggestion box functionality is described exactly there.

Hope this helps.